# How to hide endpoints based on Profiles in Spring Boot and Spring doc?

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

I am working on `Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE and SpringDoc UI and Open API Specification OAS3` and I found very related question here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/201.

I've 4 Profiles say Dev, Stage, UAT and Prod and say I've Student API, Employee API and Department API.

I want for UAT and Prod profiles, I want to hide Department API. How can we do not ?

Comment: Jeff Cook, isn't your question seems to be answered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use groups: Declare each of your API in groups.

- https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-define-multiple-openapi-definitions-in-one-spring-boot-project

And, add the @Profile annotation together with @Bean annotation for the group definition: This will help you display the OpenAPI spec depending on your spring profiles

```
@Bean
@Profile("!prod")
public GroupedOpenApi actuatorApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("Actuator")
            .pathsToMatch("/actuator/**")
            .pathsToExclude("/actuator/health/*")
            .build();
}
```